# Displaying individual post ids of queried columns in a php while loop with jquery

Tags: php

Am undoubtedly a fresher on the web programming stuff but I got this problem that I got to fix. Hoping you guys help me out.

Alright, am trying to display rows from the My SQL database into a div using the while loop. But when I want to alert the i d of each result using j Query, it shows me only the i d of the first displayed data.

...

```
var post_id = $('#hide').prop(value);  
alert(post_id);
```

...

Now, on clicking the submit button. It alerts the i d of the first displayed data from My SQL. Please what am I missing or need to add to fix this.

Comment: what "while" loop, and what "mysql"? and what "php"?

Comment: when having a problem with *database code*, it is usually extremely helpful to actually **include** said *database code*

Comment: show the full code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are using id and id works for a single element. For more then one occurrence try class instead, like:

PHP:

```
for($results as $result)
{
    echo '<li class="link">'.$result.'</li>';
}
```

JS:

```
$('.link').click(function(){
    var post = $(this).html();    // here you can use val(), id() also depends on your code
    alert(post);    // you will get data for the li on which you click
});
```

Comment: First, thanks Mayank Pandeyz. It solved the problem. Lastly, Am sorry for the title of the question, I'll fix it now so others can benefit from it. Thanks guys.

Comment: Sounds great :)
Enjoy the coding

Comment: Hope now the title is much better.